# const {something} = require (something) doesn't work in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, require

`const something = require(something)` 
works perfectly

But 
`const {something} = require(something)` gives an error

```
const {something} = require(something);
      ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

Comment: Upgrade your NodeJS versoin

Comment: This is indeed valid syntax - which version of node are you using?

Comment: Thnx guys. It was node version problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do is called destructuring on declarations and is available since NodeJS version 6.4+, to be able to use it you either need to upgrade the version of NodeJS you're using, or if you need to use earlier versions, you should use babel to transpile your code.